# Breaking nested while loops with boolean

Tags: python

So my program tries to find Pythagorean Triplet, where `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` AND `a+b+c=1000`. So everything works well, but program finds the answer quite early in the program runtime, so I would like to break somehow out of all the loops. I am trying simple boolean method, but for some reason my cycle stops after 1 second. If I remove `exit = True` then everything works (but no break obviously).

P.s. it's also same problem if I use simple `0` or `1` integers to check that.
Can anyone give me ideas why this is not working?

```
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
exit = False
while (i < 999 and exit == False):
    while (j < 999 and exit == False):
        while (k < 999 and exit == False):
            if i*i + j*j == k*k:                        
                if i + j + k == 1000:
                    exit = True
                    ii = i
                    jj = j
                    kk = k
            k += 1
        j += 1
        k = 1
    i += 1
    j = 1
i = 1
print('result: %d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2' % (ii, jj, kk))
```

Comment: Holy nested loops! I'd use `for` loops for this anyway, and you can use an *exception* to break out of a set of loops fast.

Comment: Or simply wrap this in a function and `return`

Comment: I know that there are other methods for achieving same goal, but why is this exact thing not working I am wondering. But thanks for ideas.

Comment: You don't need the loop for `k`; `k = 1000 - i - j`.

Comment: OP, it seems you are solving project euler. As usual, there is a better way to generate pythagorean triplets, as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple).

Comment: You are initializing `i`, `j`, and `k` somewhere prior to your `while` loop, right?

Comment: Does this even work without an error? You're defining your variables after the relevant while loop

Comment: Ok guys, I it's not efficient, etc, I am just learning programming, but why is this simple check not working?

Comment: Closely related, possible dupe: [Generating unique, ordered Pythagorean triplets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/575117) and [What is the best way to generate Pythagorean triples?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22821210)

Comment: Yes, I initialize i, j and k, and it solves the problem, but I need to wait until it finishes running all the cycles.

Comment: I tried this code with `i`, `j`, and `k` initialized to 1 and it exited as desired. With a `print` for every increment to `i`, `j`, or `k`, one for spotting the exit, and one for reporting the actual result it wrote 198777652 lines out of the 994011994 for the non-exit solution (998 * 998 * 988 + 1 + 1 for exiting and answer).

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yep, the problem was that I initialized to 0, stupid mistake.

Comment: I see your problem is solved - one style note is that it's not considered Pythonic to compare to boolean values directly (`exit == False`). Instead, you'd usually write `while i < 999 and not exit:`. With parens to taste.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper gotcha, changed my code how you said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem you have is simply that your code *does meet the criteria you set*, when

```
ii == 0
jj == 500
kk == 500
```

If you don't want this trivial solution, you should initialise to `1` at the start (or, better, spot the trivial opportunity to factor out duplication and set e.g. `j = 1` in only one place).

Comment: Yes, initializing counters to 1 solved the issue, but I still don't understand your explanation on what is wrong :p

Comment: @user3763437 what do you mean you don't understand? It was wrong because you started with `i == 0`, which gave a trivial solution you didn't want.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a Generator Function:

```
>>> def pythagorean_triangles(target):
...     for a in range(1, target):
...         for b in range(1, target):
...             for c in range(1, target):
...                 if a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2 and a + b + c == target:
...                     yield a, b, c
...
>>> triangles = pythagorean_triangles(1000)
>>> next(triangles)
(200, 375, 425)
```

Comment: Just a question about generator. `next` means that we run generator until we get `yield`, and then stop right?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are a great way to do this early exit logic. I've also switched your loops to use the `xrange()` builtin, which cleans up some of your surrounding logic.

```
def triplet():
    for i in xrange(1000):
        for j in xrange(1000):
            for k in xrange(1000):
                if i*i + j*j == k*k:                    
                    if i + j + k == 1000:
                        return (i, j, k)

i, j, k = triplet()
print('result: %d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2' % (i, j, k))
```

Note that from here, there's a number of optimizations that you can make.

- Like that given an `i` and `j`, you only need to test one `k`, that is `k == 1000 - i - j`.
- Like that if you've tested `i == 1` and `j == 2`, you don't need to test `i == 2` and `j == 1`. They will have the same result.

Additionally, if you wanted to skip `0` in the loop, you could do `xrange(1, 1000)`. `xrange()` allows you to pass a start and an end position.

Comment: It's a nice hack. IMO such things should be supported directly by the language :(

Comment: @Elazar: Python rejected the common solution to nested loop breaking: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/

Comment: Yep, this method works well, and simpler, thanks for idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using a pythonic way to solve the problem:

```
[(a,b,c) for a,b,c in itertools.product(range(0,999), repeat=3) if (a**2 + b**2 == c**2) and (a + b + c == 1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already been suggested how to refactor the code to avoid the need to break loops in the first place, and personally I would use a generator function [solution of @pillmuncher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688038/545027) (if still considering the use of loops at all).

Here is just an example of how you can break a loop without using a boolean flag:

```
i = 1
while i < 999:
    j = 1
    while j < 999:
        k = 1
        while k < 999:
            if i*i + j*j == k*k and i + j + k == 1000:
                ii, jj, kk = i, j, k
            else:
                k += 1
                continue
            break
        else:
            j += 1
            continue
        break
    else:
        i += 1
        continue
    break
print('result: %d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2' % (ii, jj, kk))
```

Or, using more neat `for ... in range(...)` (or better `xrange` in Python 2) loop:

```
for i in range(1, 999):
    for j in range(1, 999):
        for k in range(1, 999):
            if i*i + j*j == k*k and i + j + k == 1000:
                ii, jj, kk = i, j, k
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            continue
        break
    else:
        continue
    break
print('result: %d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2' % (ii, jj, kk))
```