# Generate cuboids with integer sides and diagonals: how to improve the time complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I quickly wrote this code to test when all sides and diagonals of a cuboid a,b,c,d,e and f are all integers. It seems to work just fine but it takes way too much time for higher and higher values to loop through (for ex 10000+).

Is there any way to make this code run faster ? or maybe someway to get rid of that nasty three nested for loops ?

I thought of a few ways to reduce the complexity of this code but it doesn't go through all combinations which is something I want to happen.

```js
const generate_good_cuboid = () => {
  let good_couples = [];
  let couples = [];
  for (let a = 1; a < 10000; a++) {
    for (let b = 1; b < 10000; b++) {
      for (let c = 1; c < 10000; c++) {
        let e_squared = Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2);
        let e = Math.sqrt(e_squared);
        if (Number.isInteger(e)) {
          let d_squared = Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
          let d = Math.sqrt(d_squared);
          if (Number.isInteger(d)) {
            let f_squared = Math.pow(b, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2);
            let f = Math.sqrt(f_squared);
            if (Number.isInteger(f)) {
              good_couples.push({ a, b, c, d, e, f });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return couples;
};


console.log(generate_good_cuboid());
```

Comment: Why are `e` and `d` flipped?

Comment: Did you mean to `return good_couples`? The `couples` array is always empty.

Comment: There are some simple things you can do, like square the values with `a*a` instead of a call to `Math.pow()` and only compute those squares once per relevant loop, but to really improve the algorithmic efficiency you're going to need a completely different approach.

Comment: One thing to consider: there are only so many numbers between 1 and whatever that have integer square roots. If you pre-compute those, then there's a lot less math to do. You could also pre-compute the pairs of squared integers that sum to a perfect square.

Comment: @Pointy Doing a set lookup is not necessarily faster than doing some simple math. You'd have to benchmark, and it would probably depend a lot on the particular machine (and in general, on your willingness to trade space for speed).

Comment: @Bergi I would bet that it's cheaper than a call to `Math.sqrt()`, but that's my 1980 brain talking.

Comment: @Pointy My 1990s brain is not certain and says you should measure :-) It's definitely a worthy approach that should be tried; and for the loops to choose `a`, `b`, `c` I would definitely recommend it, just for the square-ness checks I'm not certain it would be faster.

Comment: Is isInteger going to be accurate enough, given the messiness of sqrt calculations? I don't know, just asking.

Comment: @AHaworth I wondered that too. You could round the sqrt result to the nearest integer then check e*e == e_squared etc. instead is using IsInteger.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses the [Tree of primitive Pythagorian triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) to generate all Pythagorian triples whose greatest element is less than your limit.

Then it creates a graph (adjacency list) where one integer has a link with another if they are the lesser two members of a Pythagorian triple.

Finally it checks if these can be combined to the desired combinations of a, b, and c:

```js
function* pythagorianTriples(limit) {
    const ABC = [
        [[1, -2, 2], [2, -1, 2], [2, -2, 3]],
        [[1,  2, 2], [2,  1, 2], [2,  2, 3]],
        [[-1, 2, 2], [-2, 1, 2], [-2, 2, 3]]
    ]
    let triples = [[3, 4, 5]];
    while (triples.length) {
        const children = [];
        for (const triple of triples) {
            const sorted = triple.toSorted((a, b) => a - b);
            if (sorted[1] >= limit) continue; // The limit applies to a, b, not c
            // Yield multiples of this primitive pythagorian triple
            for (let i = 1; sorted[1] * i < limit; i++) {
                yield [sorted[0] * i, sorted[1] * i, sorted[2] * i];
            }
            // Get the triple's three children in the tree of Pythagorian triples:
            children.push(...ABC.map(mat =>
                mat.map(row => 
                    row[0] * triple[0] + row[1] * triple[1] + row[2] * triple[2]
                )
            ));
        }
        triples = children;
    }
}

function generateGoodCuboids(limit) {
    const pairSide = Array.from({length: limit}, (_, i) => new Set);
    const triples = [...pythagorianTriples(limit)];
    // Link pairs that belong to same Pythagorian triple; for fast lookup
    for (const [a, b] of triples) {
        pairSide[a].add(b);
        pairSide[b].add(a);
    }
    // Find valid combinations
    const solutions = [];
    for (const [a, b] of triples) {
        for (const c of pairSide[a]) {
            if (c >= b && pairSide[b].has(c)) solutions.push([a, b, c]);
        }
    }
    // For convenience, sort them:
    return solutions.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);
}

const cuboids = generateGoodCuboids(1000);
console.log(`There are ${cuboids.length} solutions for sides < 1000:`);
for (const cuboid of cuboids) console.log(...cuboid);

// For 10 times more:
const cuboids2 = generateGoodCuboids(10000);
console.log(`There are ${cuboids2.length} solutions for sides < 10000`);

// For 10 times more:
const cuboids3 = generateGoodCuboids(100000);
console.log(`There are ${cuboids3.length} solutions for sides < 100000`);
```

The script finds 10 solutions (ignoring permutations) when the limit is 1000; it repeats the job for 10000 (151 solutions) and 100000 (1714 solutions).

Comment: Alexander Nenashev's code finds 906 solutions with sides under 10,000.

Comment: @Simon, their deleted program generated duplicates and permutations of the same solution. However, I had applied the limit (10000) to the *diagonals*, which was not what the asker intended. I have now updated the answer to apply that limit to the sides only, and so for sides under 10,000 this leads to 151 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial optimisation would be to compute `d` (from `a` and `b`) and check for its integer-ness before looping over all `c`.

Further, you could avoid generating duplicates such as `a=3, b=4` and `a=4, b=3` by limiting your results to `a < b < c`, and permute your solutions if you need all of them. Then you can optimise `for (let b = a; b < 10000; b++)` and `for (let c = b; c < 10000; c++)` (although this doesn't really change complexity).

Last but not least, you could generate all known-good sets of Pythagorean triples up-front (only once), and then just search through those to find two triples (triangles) that share one side, and check whether the other two legs (catheti) form a Pythogorean triple as well. Use any of the known algorithms ([generating Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples), [tree of primitive Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples), [Efficiently find all the Pythagorean triplets](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250855/efficiently-find-all-the-pythagorean-triplets-where-all-numbers-less-than-1000), [best way to generate Pythagorean triples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821210/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-pythagorean-triples) etc.) for the first part.